# How to get Push Notification through GCM server through phonegap

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have tried this but i did not get the correct one so please help me. and i need source code for push-notification for android using GCM server.

Answer (score 0):

Start by following a tutorial like this one : http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/

And then come and tell us if something went wrong. I managed to get it working in a few hours of work, you should be fine with this tutorial.